# Cardinality arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a cardinality such that  $\mathfrak{a}\cdot\aleph_{0}=\mathfrak{a}$, then $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}$

Is there an "elegant" way of proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

$$ \mathfrak{a} \; \leq \; \mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{a} \; = \; \mathfrak{a}\cdot 2 \; \leq \; \mathfrak{a}\cdot\aleph_{0}=\mathfrak{a} $$

in which the two inequalities must be equalities?

Comment: How do I prove that $\mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{a} \; = \; \mathfrak{a}\cdot 2$ for non-finite sets?

Comment: *for non-finite sets* --- You mean "for a non-finite cardinal $\mathfrak{a}.$ This equality is very basic and should be in most any set theory text.

Comment: Well, I have to prove it. I managed to do it anyways, thanks.

Comment: @vpam: If you don't have to prove this in a very axiomatic and formal way, then it's probably immediate from your definitions of the operations: Let $A$ be a set with cardinality $\mathfrak{a}.$ Then $A \times \{0,\,1\}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{a} \cdot 2$ and $(A \times \{0\}) \; \cup \; (A \times \{1\})$ (a disjoint union) has cardinality $\mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{a}.$ Now simply observe that $A \times \{0,\,1\} \; = \; (A \times \{0\}) \; \cup \; (A \times \{1\})$ (i.e. you don't need to put any effort into defining a bijective function from one set to the other set).

Comment: $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\aleph_{0}+\mathfrak{a}\cdot\aleph_{0}=(\aleph_{0}+\aleph_{0})\mathfrak{a}=\aleph_{0}\cdot\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a} $

Answer (score 0):

Use $\mathfrak{a}\le2\mathfrak{a}\le\aleph_0\mathfrak{a}=a$.